# PHP Sessions variables

Tags: php, session, hyperlink, store

I have 3 pages, one HTML page (session.html) and 2 PHP pages (session.php & sessiona.php). The html page has a form on it with only 2 fields, one being a text box (customername) and other being a selection list (hobby). The action on the HTML page is to send to session.php in which i store the variables in this manner :

```
<body>

<?php
session_start();

$_session['name'] = $_POST['customername'];
$_session['hobby'] = $_POST['hobby'];

$name = $_session['name'];
$hobby = $_session['hobby'];

?>

<p><a href="sessiona.php">Sessiona</a></p>

</body>
```

The point of session.php is only to store the variables and only display a link to sessiona.php which i want to retrieve the stored variables from sesssion.php and diplay them. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: one way is to use cookies.

Comment: It's not $_session[] it's $_SESSION[]

Comment: Excuse me, but `$_session` is the same as `$_SESSION`?

Comment: You cannot have *any* output before `session_start()` or it won't work and will generate an error.

Comment: @sgroves : storing data in cookies is a bad habit. It's better to store an ID (such as SESSION ids).

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['name']`, `echo $_SESSION['hobby']`

Comment: @Dawson i have tried that but nothing was displayed

Comment: @mimipc i have changed all my $_session to $_SESSION, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should suffice to set

```
session_start();
```

in your sessiona.php where you can get the variables in the manner you suggested:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name']; 
$hobby = $_SESSION['hobby'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Any page to start the session variable's creation

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['customername'];
$_SESSION['hobby'] = $_POST['hobby'];
?>
<html>...</html>
```

Any page to retrieve that session data after it's created

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) { $name = $_SESSION['name'] }
if(isset($_SESSION['hobby'])) { $hobby = $_SESSION['hobby'] }
?>
<html>...<?php echo($name) ?>...or...<?php echo($_SESSION['name'])?>...</html>
```

Note: you will want to check for that session variable to ensure you don't throw an error on echo. `isset()`, `!empty()`, etc.